# SQLAlchemy intricacies with relationships and uncommitted objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy via Flask, and I want to add simple personal messaging to my webapp.  The model has a `User` class, a `PersonalMessage` class and a `PersonalMessageUser` association class, with the latter setting up relationships to the former two—nothing fancy.  Here is a stripped down version:

```
import collections
import datetime

from flaskext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from . import app

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

def current_ts():
    return datetime.datetime.utcnow()

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(127), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {0.username!r} (#{0.id})>'.format(self)

class PersonalMessage(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(127), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=current_ts)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<PersonalMessage {0.subject!r} (#{0.id})>'.format(self)

    def __init__(self, subject, body, from_, to=None, cc=None, bcc=None):
        self.subject = subject
        self.body = body
        if not to and not cc and not bcc:
            raise ValueError, 'No recipients defined'
        self._pm_users.append(PersonalMessageUser(
            message=self, user_type='From', user=from_,
        ))
        for type, values in {'To': to, 'CC': cc, 'BCC': bcc}.items():
            if values is None:
                continue
            if not isinstance(values, collections.Iterable):
                values = [values]
            for value in values:
                self._pm_users.append(PersonalMessageUser(
                    message=self, user=value, user_type=type,
                ))

class PersonalMessageUser(db.Model):
    pm_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(PersonalMessage.id), nullable=False,
                      primary_key=True)
    message = db.relationship(PersonalMessage, backref='_pm_users',
                              lazy='subquery')
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(User.id), nullable=False,
                        primary_key=True)
    user = db.relationship(User, backref='_personal_messages')
    user_type = db.Column(
        db.Enum('From', 'To', 'CC', 'BCC', name='user_type'),
        nullable=False, default='To', primary_key=True,
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            '<PersonalMessageUser '
            '{0.user_type}: {0.user.username!r} '
            '(PM #{0.pm_id}: {0.message.subject!r})>'
        ).format(self)
```

Everything works fine basically, but I noticed something strange when I played around with it in the Python interpreter: when I create a new `PersonalMessage` with one sender and one recipient, the `_pm_users` backref actually lists each user twice.  Once the object has been committed to the database, it looks okay, though.  See the following session as an example:

```
>>> al = User(username='al')
>>> db.session.add(al)
>>> steve = User(username='steve')
>>> db.session.add(steve)
>>> db.session.commit()
BEGIN (implicit)
INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?)
('al',)
INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?)
('steve',)
COMMIT
>>> pm = PersonalMessage('subject', 'body', from_=al, to=steve)
>>> pm._pm_users
BEGIN (implicit)
SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username 
FROM user 
WHERE user.id = ?
(1,)
SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username 
FROM user 
WHERE user.id = ?
(2,)
[<PersonalMessageUser From: u'al' (PM #None: 'subject')>,
 <PersonalMessageUser From: u'al' (PM #None: 'subject')>,
 <PersonalMessageUser To: u'steve' (PM #None: 'subject')>,
 <PersonalMessageUser To: u'steve' (PM #None: 'subject')>]
>>> len(pm._pm_users)
4
>>> db.session.add(pm)
>>> pm._pm_users
[<PersonalMessageUser From: u'al' (PM #None: 'subject')>,
 <PersonalMessageUser From: u'al' (PM #None: 'subject')>,
 <PersonalMessageUser To: u'steve' (PM #None: 'subject')>,
 <PersonalMessageUser To: u'steve' (PM #None: 'subject')>]
>>> db.session.commit()
INSERT INTO personal_message (subject, body, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
('subject', 'body', '2011-08-10 19:48:15.641249')
INSERT INTO personal_message_user (pm_id, user_id, user_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
((1, 1, 'From'), (1, 2, 'To'))
COMMIT
>>> pm._pm_users
BEGIN (implicit)
SELECT personal_message.id AS personal_message_id,
    personal_message.subject AS personal_message_subject,
    personal_message.body AS personal_message_body,
    personal_message.date AS personal_message_date 
FROM personal_message 
WHERE personal_message.id = ?
(1,)
SELECT personal_message_user.pm_id AS personal_message_user_pm_id,
    personal_message_user.user_id AS personal_message_user_user_id,
    personal_message_user.user_type AS personal_message_user_user_type 
FROM personal_message_user 
WHERE ? = personal_message_user.pm_id
(1,)
SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username 
FROM user 
WHERE user.id = ?
(1,)
SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username 
FROM user 
WHERE user.id = ?
(2,)
[<PersonalMessageUser From: u'al' (PM #1: u'subject')>,
 <PersonalMessageUser To: u'steve' (PM #1: u'subject')>]
```

At least the final result is what I expect it to be, but each user showing up twice before committing makes me feel uncomfortable; I’d like to understand what’s going on there.  Do I miss something in my `relationship`/`backref` setup, or shall I just ignore this?

Comment: Why PersonalMessageUser.user_type defined as `primary_key`?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415842/sqlalchemy-with-multiple-primary-keys-does-not-automatically-set-any

Comment: @estin There is single compound primary key (`pm_id, user_id, user_type`) and it's common solution for association table. The question you refer to is not relevant since all columns composing the primary key are set manually (directly or through relationships).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call

```
self._pm_users.append(PersonalMessageUser(
    message=self, user_type='From', user=from_,
))
```

you have twice append object to _pm_users list

This should work for you:

```
PersonalMessageUser(
    message=self, user_type='From', user=from_,
)
```

or

```
self._pm_users.append(
    PersonalMessageUser(user_type='From', user=from_,)
)
```

When set `relationship property`, sqlalchemy associate objects for you

Comment: Of course you are right; I missed the obvious thing.  Thanks for pointing me!